# Is anybody already reviewing edits?

Tags: support

For review you need 1000 rep - but we do not have any user so far with such reputation.

What is currently happening to edits?

Comment: I had an edit made to one of my questions and it was accepted by a few different users.  I'll try and find their usernames.  I also submitted an edit and it was accepted but I'm not sure by who.

Comment: Looks like this was just a tag edit: http://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/419/revisions

Answer (score 5):

The reputation requirements are lowered both during the private and the public beta to allow more users to bootstrap these activities. But while the most avid users are building up reputation (even at these reduced levels), the Community Team at Stack Exchange takes care of these functions for the early community.

That's why we say it is so important to [**Vote Early, Vote Often**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/). A site needs on-going, sustained voting to build a class of core users who help run and govern the site. Voting, editing, closing, and other self-moderation privileges are the primary mechanism through which the community governs the site on a day to day basis.